# Automate joining lines in text blocks (perhaps with SHIFT+j) but do not join blocks

Tags: neovim, regular-expression, replace

I have the lastest versions of arch and nvim which I am using.

I have a text that looks like this

```
the slow brown  
fox jumped  
over a   
bridge  

the blind brown  
fox stumbled  
upon a   
badger
  

the quick brown  
fox jumped  
over a   
lazy dog  

the quick brown  
fox jumped  
over a  
cow
```

Each line ends with a `\n`.

There are 100's of paragraphs. Each paragraph is unique.

I want it to look like this:

```
the slow brown fox jumped over a bridge  

the blind brown fox stumbled upon a badger
  
the quick brown fox jumped over a lazy dog  

the quick brown fox jumped over a cow
```

.. etc

Without using `n J` hundereds of times how can I automate this with a command?

Comment: I found this `:g/^./ .,/^$/-1 join`
here
https://superuser.com/questions/200423/join-lines-inside-paragraphs-in-vim
which seems to work

Comment: Heh, yep @Kes, I think I've written it here too

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/26635/10604

Comment: Hi @D-Ben-Knoble yes it does. Thank you for your help :) Appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I've answered this before](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/26635/10604), but the general strategy is this: globally `join` from the start of a paragraph to the end (given by `/^$/-`). But we have to handle the last line of the document specially. The easiest version is

```
:$put =''
:global/./,/^$/-join
:$delete
```

where we make a blank line at the end, do our join (which doesn't fail on the last line, now), and then remove the spurious blank line at the end. Takes about 30s interactively, or less if you abbreviate:

```
:$pu ='' | g/./,/^$/-j
:$d
```

(because `:global` eats `|` for its command, the `delete` has to be done separately, or you have to use `:execute`, which I think is definitely slower to type.)

Comment: I've now a feeling I asked this before somewhere, possibly here. Apologies.