# au VimLeave ex mode command not returning output

Tags: autocmd, external-command, ex-mode

I've been using the `fmt` Unix tool to standardise line length, for example `:%! fmt -999` (thanks to [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26641/26984)).

I'd like to do this by default in Markdown files, so in `~/.vim/ftplugin/markdown.vim` I tried:

```
au VimLeave <buffer> :%!fmt -9999 | w
```

But surprisingly when I leave I am stopped by a confirmation message, and my buffer has been overwritten by

```
22:39  up 14 days, 23:53, 3 users, load averages: 2.88 2.68 2.72
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@  IDLE WHAT
joshfriedlander console  -                10Mar21 14days -
joshfriedlander s000     -                10Mar21 14days /Users/joshfriedlander/anacon
joshfriedlander s001     -                22:07       - w
```

However when I use an `aucmd` not related to leaving, such as

```
au InsertLeave <buffer> :%!fmt -9999
```

it works as expected.

What is going on here? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:!` sees the bar as part of its argument (I forget the help-reference; edits appreciated).

So you have to write

```
execute '%!fmt -999' | write
```

The extra output is from the `w` program run by the shell, which is similar to `who`.